# MVC4 oAuth causing null value exception: Provider is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth

My Issue is similar to this post.
[MVC4 oAuth causing null value exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263938/mvc4-oauth-causing-null-value-exception)

However, I have not changed the button to an image input. When debugging the values are all present on the for each loop that creates the buttons to the OAuth providers. Here:

```
@model ICollection<AuthenticationClientData>

@if (Model.Count == 0)
{
  <div class="message-info">
    <p>There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=252166">this article</a>
    for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.</p>
  </div>
}
else
{
  using (Html.BeginForm("ExternalLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset id="socialLoginList">
      <legend>Log in using another service</legend>
      <p>
      @foreach (AuthenticationClientData p in Model)
      {
        <button type="submit" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName" title="Log in using your @p.DisplayName account">@p.DisplayName</button>
      }
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any other situations that would cause the provider to be returning null and throwing an error?

EDIT: Infact after some more debuggin I have found that the provider string is not posted back into this method in the account controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    return new ExternalLoginResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}
```

Does anybody know why or how this is happening? if you need any more code, please ask.

EDIT: here is an image of the values present in the view, but missing in the post. any suggestions most welcome.

[image: Breakpoints image of values present on page load and then missing in the post]

EDIT:Added the entire view for the log in page form. the provider value is not submitted when the button is submitted, this is confirmed in fiddler post

EDIT: If i add a class on to the buttons and then add a hidden field to the form called provider. I am then able to set its value using jquery. This value is then submitted with the form and sure enough it works.

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="provider" id="provider" />
@foreach(.... etc
<button class="test" type="submit" name="provider" value="@p.AuthenticationClient.ProviderName" title="Log in using your @p.DisplayName account">@p.DisplayName</button>
```

and then

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.test').click(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $('#provider').val($(this).val());
            return true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

If someone could tell me why this is and how to fix it properly that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Any faulting client scripts that are executed on form submission or scripts that disable submit buttons (external provider buttons in your case) will cause null values. Make sure that ExternalLogin provider Form is posted to its ActionResult without any exceptions.

Comment: i do not get any exceptions and i have no javascript errors or client scripts intercepting the post.

Comment: The Fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) might help in debugging. Check the submission traffic.

Comment: I cant see the provider attribute in the post. i dont know why... its just not there. it should be. the other parameter Return url is present. i'll update the original to contain the entire form object so you can see it in situ.